# Reduce a set into linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider the vectors in a set

> $\text{span} \{<1, 4, 0, 2>, <3, 1, 4, 0>, <-1, 7, -4, 4>, <0, 11, -4, 6>\}$

the set is not linearly independent, what is a strategy into finding a useless vector and removing it from the span so the set becomes linearly independent?

Comment: As with many things in introductory linear algebra, row reduction

Comment: @JMoravitz, but what after row reducing? I have the RREF, but how can I remove a vector from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 & -1 & 0 \\ 4 & 1 & 7 & 11 \\ 0 & 4 & -4 & -4 \\ 2 & 0 & 4 & 6 \end{pmatrix}_.$

If you row reduce $A$, you get the following matrix:

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 2 & 3 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}_.$$

Picking out the vectors corresponding to the columns with leading ones, gives:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 4 \\ 0 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} \text{ and } \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 1 \\ 4 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

These will be a basis for the span of the columns of $A$.

Comment: I see. In general, does this hold? Ie. say I had a matrix with the setup: [leading 1, no leading 1, leading 1, no leading 1] then is the basis of col space of A the first and third vectors of the original matrix?

Comment: Great answer tw

Comment: Yes this works in general, as you described.